# Coredata predicate IN operator with like or contain

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, predicate

I have two arrays on which I have to do the wildcard search and I am using the IN operator but the IN operator gives me the exact matching but I want to fetch all the results that contains the searchTerm. Is this possible through IN operator or do I have to manually loop through all the records and match pick the record that I want.

Current Code :

```
        NSArray *filteredArray = [brandsFabric filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.color_name IN  %@ OR self.subcategory_name IN %@",colorNamesArray,patternNamesArray]];
```

Desired functionality something like this:

```
        NSArray *filteredArray = [brandsFabric filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.color_name IN like/contains %@ OR self.subcategory_name IN like/contains %@",colorNamesArray,patternNamesArray]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very expensive operation, but you can try:

```
NSMutableArray *predicates = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *name in colorNames) {
   [predicates addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
       @"color_name CONTAINS[cd] %@", name]];
}
for (NSString *name in subcategoryNames) {
   [predicates addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
       @"subcategory_name CONTAINS[cd] %@", name]];
}
NSPredicate *final = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicates];
```

Maybe even a subquery is in order here. *(experimental)*

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
  @"((SUBQUERY(%@, $x, color_name CONTAINS[cd] $x).@count != 0) OR "
  @"((SUBQUERY(%@, $x, category_name CONTAINS[cd] $x).@count != 0)", 
  colorNames, categoryNames];
```

Comment: As you mention this is an expensive operation. More so when compounding with OR. If the case were to compound with AND it is actually much more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

It goes like this : `CONTAINS[cd] %@` in place of `IN`

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't look for value ((
    Black
)) in string (Blue); value is not a string '

Comment: i am getting this error because contains does not work with collections as I was using arrays with IN operator.